# JComboBox in a public class

Tags: java, swing, class, jcombobox

`enter code here`Hi I'm new developer in Java I want to put a JComboBox in a public class to get the selected item  but Java don't recognize it for example i want to do this.

```
myComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

and when i try to put a JTextField it works fine.

Sorry for my expression I'm not speak English very well

Thats my code

```
package guarderia;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class enfermedades extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtid;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField txtnom;
    private static JTable table;



    //VARIABLES PARA CONEXION A MYSQL
    static Connection con;
    static CallableStatement ps;
    static ResultSet rs;
    static DefaultTableModel tm;
    static Statement sql;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    enfermedades frame = new enfermedades();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    llenar();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public enfermedades() {


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1211, 663);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 1624, 53);
        contentPane.add(panel);

        JLabel lblEnfermedades = new JLabel("ENFERMEDADES");
        lblEnfermedades.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblEnfermedades.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 19));
        lblEnfermedades.setBounds(12, 12, 231, 41);
        panel.add(lblEnfermedades);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setLayout(null);
        panel_1.setBounds(10, 102, 426, 510);
        contentPane.add(panel_1);

        JLabel lblIdNio = new JLabel("ID Niño");
        lblIdNio.setBounds(12, 30, 70, 15);
        panel_1.add(lblIdNio);

        txtid = new JTextField();
        txtid.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                int c = e.getKeyChar();
                if (c < '0' || c > '9') e.consume();
                    }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                con= (Connection) conexion.conectar();
                try {
                    if (txtid.getText().equals(""))
                    {
                        txtnom.setText("");
                    }
                    ps = (CallableStatement) con.prepareCall("{call select_nin (?) }");
                    ps.setLong(1, Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText()));



                    ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();


                    if (res.next())
                    {
                    String tipo = res.getString("Nombre");
                    txtnom.setText(tipo);
                    llenar();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtnom.setText(null);

                    }
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1 );
                    }





            }


        });
        txtid.setColumns(10);
        txtid.setBounds(120, 28, 146, 19);
        panel_1.add(txtid);



        JLabel cbi = new JLabel("Enfermedad");
        cbi.setBounds(12, 95, 194, 15);
        panel_1.add(cbi);

        JLabel lblTratamiento = new JLabel("Tratamiento");
        lblTratamiento.setBounds(12, 130, 194, 15);
        panel_1.add(lblTratamiento);

        JButton btnNueva = new JButton("Nueva");
        btnNueva.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            }
        });
        btnNueva.setBounds(282, 90, 88, 25);
        panel_1.add(btnNueva);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBounds(12, 157, 402, 118);
        panel_1.add(textPane);

        JLabel lblFechaDeteccion = new JLabel("Fecha Deteccion");
        lblFechaDeteccion.setBounds(12, 299, 194, 15);
        panel_1.add(lblFechaDeteccion);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(135, 297, 95, 19);
        panel_1.add(textField_1);

        JLabel lblNombre = new JLabel("Nombre");
        lblNombre.setBounds(12, 61, 70, 15);
        panel_1.add(lblNombre);

        txtnom = new JTextField();
        txtnom.setEditable(false);
        txtnom.setColumns(10);
        txtnom.setBounds(120, 56, 294, 19);
        panel_1.add(txtnom);

        JLabel lblMedidadRecomendadas = new JLabel("Medidas recomendadas");
        lblMedidadRecomendadas.setBounds(12, 330, 194, 15);
        panel_1.add(lblMedidadRecomendadas);

        JTextPane textPane_1 = new JTextPane();
        textPane_1.setBounds(12, 355, 402, 93);
        panel_1.add(textPane_1);

        JButton btnGuardar = new JButton("Guardar");
        btnGuardar.setBounds(297, 470, 117, 25);
        panel_1.add(btnGuardar);

        JComboBox cbx = new JComboBox();
        cbx.setBounds(120, 90, 146, 24);
        panel_1.add(cbx);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setLayout(null);
        panel_2.setBackground(new Color(220, 20, 60));
        panel_2.setBounds(10, 65, 426, 32);
        contentPane.add(panel_2);

        JLabel lblRegistrarEnfermedad = new JLabel("Registrar enfermedad");
        lblRegistrarEnfermedad.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblRegistrarEnfermedad.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 19));
        lblRegistrarEnfermedad.setBounds(12, 5, 401, 23);
        panel_2.add(lblRegistrarEnfermedad);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(448, 102, 751, 510);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setLayout(null);
        panel_3.setBackground(new Color(128, 0, 128));
        panel_3.setBounds(448, 65, 751, 32);
        contentPane.add(panel_3);

        JLabel lblEnfermedades_1 = new JLabel("Enfermedades");
        lblEnfermedades_1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblEnfermedades_1.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 19));
        lblEnfermedades_1.setBounds(12, 5, 401, 23);
        panel_3.add(lblEnfermedades_1);
    }



    public static void llenar()
    {
        try
        {

            con = (Connection) conexion.conectar();
            String[]titulos={"ID", "ENFERMEDAD", "DESCRIPCION", "RIESGO CONTAGIO", "TIPO"};
            String cmd = "select * from enfermedades";
            tm = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);
            sql = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery(cmd);
            String[]fila = new String[5];

            while(rs.next())
            {
                fila[0]= rs.getString("id");
                fila[1]= rs.getString("enfermedad");
                fila[2]= rs.getString("descripcion");
                fila[3]= rs.getString("riesgo");
                fila[4]= rs.getString("tipo");  

                tm.addRow(fila);

            }
            table.setModel(tm);
            TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
            columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(3);
            columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
            columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(290);



        }
        catch(Exception d)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, d + " No se pudo conectar.");
        }


    }
     public void ns()
     {
         cbx. //this is where not recognize the jcombobox
     }

}
```

Comment: please show the error message and the context in code where have this code

Comment: Several issues: You usually do not want to make your fields public as this increases the risk of bugs. Better to leave it private and then allow outside classes ability to get its selection via a controlled public method. The next big issue is that we have little knowledge of the structure of the program or how you're trying to use this component. Please add more information and pertinent code to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the updated question. That helps us a lot, 1+.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be one simply of variable scope. When you declare the cbx variable within your constructor, it is visible **only** within the constructor. If you move the declaration to the class, then the variable becomes visible throughout the class.

So if you move `JComboBox cbx = new JComboBox();` to the class level, in other words if you move this statement to just below your `private JTextField txtnom;` statement, then the cbx field will be visible within the ns method.

So in other words, make these changes:

```
public class enfermedades extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtid;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField txtnom;
    private static JTable table;

    // !! added
    private JComboBox cbx = new JComboBox();

    // ...... code removed for brevity's sake


    public enfermedades() {


        // ...... code removed for brevity's sake

        panel_1.add(btnGuardar);
        // !! JComboBox cbx = new JComboBox(); // ***** Don't declare this here ****


        // ...... code removed for brevity's sake


    }

    // ...... code removed for brevity's sake


    public void ns() {

        // cbx field is now visible here

    }
}
```

Other unrelated problems within your code:

- Avoid using null layouts and setBounds. While this might seem to newbies the easiest way to create GUI's, believe me, it's not. Much better to learn how to use the layout managers and use them.
- None of the mysql fields or the JTable table field should be static. They should be instance (non-static) fields only. This means that you shouldn't try to access them in a static way.
- the llenar method shouldn't be static, and you should call it off of the instance that you've created.
- Learn and follow Java naming conventions so that others (we) can better understand your code. Class names begin with an upper-case letter and variable and method names begin with a lower-case letter.
- Your sql code should be located in its own class and not within the GUI class's code.
- You will want to make sql calls in a separate thread off of the GUI's main event thread, the "EDT".

Answer (score 0):

Making it public magically won't make you access it anywhere from world.

You need to have that instance in order to access that.